# Closed form solution $\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \frac{\cos ^m(\theta -\psi )}{\cos ^2(\theta -\varphi )} \, \mathrm d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Concerning to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505704/91450) I finally got the following integral:
$$\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \frac{\cos ^m(\theta -\psi )}{\cos ^2(\theta -\varphi )} \, \mathrm d\theta$$
where $-\pi<\varphi,\psi\leq\pi$

*So is it possible to find the closed-form solution of that integral?*

**UPDATE**

As **Ron Gordon** pointed out if $\theta-\varphi$ everything is very bad. But can we find the solution in Cauchy principal value sense?

 For example if change variable to $\alpha=\theta-\varphi$ then
$$\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \frac{\cos ^m(\theta -\psi )}{\cos ^2(\theta -\varphi )} \, \mathrm d\theta= PV \int_{-\pi-\varphi}^{\pi-\varphi } \frac{\cos ^m(\alpha -\Delta)}{\cos ^2(\alpha)} \, \mathrm d\alpha$$
with a discontinuity at $\alpha=±n\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Then is it possible to solve it?

Comment: I don't think this converges.  What happens when $\theta+\varphi$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$?

Comment: @RonGordon and if I modify $\varphi$ to be in $\Bbb C$? with a vanishingly small positive imaginary part.

Comment: So then you are asking for the Cauchy principal value.  If that's what you want, then ask for it.

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry, I didn't think about it at first. Now I've edited the question.